# Definition for BLOCK_LIST / BLOCK_IT

Tags: tesseract

I am using tesseract ocr. I am not able to find the definition of BLOCK_LIST or BLOCK_IT. May I know where the definition of these classes are present.

Answer (score 0):

class `BLOCK_LIST` and `BLOCK_IT` are generated by a macro named `ELISTIZEH` , it is defined in `ccstruct/elst.h`